# Como puedo buscar en diferentes campos de un formulario

Tags: sql-server, pdo, busqueda

a ver si alguien puede ayudarme. Tengo un formulario de busqueda de clientes muy simple, donde se puede buscar por nombre, apellido, localidad. Ahora solo consigo que me busque por nombre, como puedo hacer para que si dejo el campo nombre vacio y relleno localidad me saque todos los clientes de esa localidad. Gracias

Esta es mi función para buscar:

```
function consultaClientes($nombre, $apellidos, $localidad, $provincia)
{
    global $db;

    $stmt = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE nombre LIKE '%".$nombre."%' OR apellidos LIKE '%".$apellidos."%' OR localidad LIKE '%".$localidad."%' OR provincia LIKE '%".$provincia."%';";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($stmt);
    $stmt->execute([$nombre, $apellidos, $localidad, $provincia]);
    $clientes = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    if(!$clientes){
        echo "!No existe ningun cliente con ese nombre";
        header("location: buscar.php");
    }

    return $clientes;
}
```

y este mi formulario:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'];
    $localidad = $_POST['localidad'];
    $provincia = $_POST['provincia'];

    $clientes = consultaClientes($nombre, $apellidos, $localidad, $provincia);

}
   
?>

<main class="contenedor seccion">
    <h1>Buscar Clientes</h1>

    <form class="formulario" method="POST">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" id="nombre" name="nombre">

            <label for="apellidos">Apellidos</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Apellidos" id="apellidos" name="apellidos">

            <label for="localidad">Localidad</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Dirección" id="localidad" name="localidad">

            <label for="provincia">Provincia</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Dirección" id="provincia" name="provincia">

        </fieldset>
        <input class="centrar" type="submit" value="Buscar" class="boton boton-verde">
    </form>
    <section class="contenedor">
        <?php foreach ($clientes as $cliente) : ?>
            <div>
                <div id="accordionPR" class="1 mt-2">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header dark-mode" id="heading0">
                            <div class="header-bar d-flex" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseP0" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="#collapseP0">
                                <h4 class="main-title-purple p-2 mt-1"><i class="fas fa-plus">&nbsp</i><span><?php echo $cliente->nombre . ' ' . $cliente->apellidos; ?></span></h4>
                            </div>
```

Perdonad que no puse el codigo. Con este codigo siempre me trae todos los resultados, le da igual que rellene el nombre o el apellido o la localidad.
A ver si con esto os aclaro algo mas.

Gracias nuevamente

Comment: Y cual es tu codigo? que intentaste? es simplemente cambiar el where...

Comment: No debe de ser complicado, recibirías los parámetros y por medio de OR podrías hacer que filtre por lo que llegue, pero como dice @gbianchi que es lo que has intentado para basarse de ahi y poder ayudarte

Comment: ¿Con ese código, si dejas vacío el nombre y pones algo que si exista en la base de datos en localidad, no te encuentra nada? mmm, me parece dudoso... aparte de la vulnerabilidad a inyección SQL, veo bien el código.

Comment: Con ese codigo si dejo todos los campos vacios y solo pongo la localidad, me trae todos los clientes sean de la localidad que sean. Igual que si en nombre pongo un nombre y dejo los demas vacio tambien me lo trae todo

Answer (score 0):

Ya me funcionó, el problema estaba al poner '%".$...."%' porque me lo traia todo, la he cambiado por esta otra y ya me funciona bien. Gracias

```
"SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE nombre LIKE '$nombre' OR apellidos LIKE '$apellidos' OR localidad LIKE '$localidad' OR provincia LIKE '$provincia';"
```